# I want to use Hooks here but don't know how . This is my code

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Problem**
I want to use hooks inside my code to get users username and password to store it into MySql i don't have any code to login but for now I just want to store username nad password. i don't know anything about hooks in react **Now my question is where and how, I can use hooks inside this code**

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import loginImg from "../../login.svg";
import Axios from "axios";

const [usernameReg, setUsernameReg] = useState("");
const [passwordReg, setPasswordReg] = useState("");
const register = () => {
  Axios.post("https://localhost3001/register", {
    username: usernameReg,
    password: passwordReg,
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
};


export const Register= () => {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    
    return (
      <div className="base-container" ref={this.props.containerRef}>
        <div className="header">Register</div>
        <div className="content">
          <div className="image">
            <img src={loginImg} />
          </div>
          <div className="form">
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="username"
                placeholder="username"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setUsernameReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="password"
                placeholder="password"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setPasswordReg(e.target.value);
                }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="footer">
          <button type="button" onClick={register} className="btn">
            Register
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: be specific to your question ? where you have to user hooks?

Comment: Your question and your code is incomplete to answer

Comment: I want to use hooks inside my code to get users username and password to store it into MySql i don't have any code to login but for now I just want to store username nad password. i don't know anything about hooks in react Now my question is where and how, I can use hooks inside this code

Comment: You have not one, but two `useState`s! Congratulations, you are using hooks. Is there anything specific you need help with? You aren't really asking a question here.

Comment: I would start with some hook tutorials and the docs.

Comment: If you get a compile or runtime error, you need to include which it is and the *full text* of the error message *in the question*.

Comment: This is the error i am getting :/   .                                  
          src\component\login\register.jsx
  Line 5:39:  React Hook "useState" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  Line 6:39:  React Hook "useState" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: I'll repeat this since you missed this and reposted your error as a comment: 
If you get a compile or runtime error, you need to include which it is and the full text of the error message **in the question**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React hooks can't be used outside of [functional components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Here, you have a class components (also can't use hooks) **Register**. You need convert it into functional component and append your state hooks into it. Also, you can [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) for momize function.

```
export const Register = (props) => {
    const [usernameReg, setUsernameReg] = useState("");
    const [passwordReg, setPasswordReg] = useState("");

    const register = useCallback(() => { //You also can use hook useCallback for memoize fucntion 
      Axios.post("https://localhost3001/register", {
        username: usernameReg,
        password: passwordReg,
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
    }, [usernameReg, passwordReg]);

    return <div className="base-container" ref={this.props.containerRef}>
        <div className="header">Register</div>
        <div className="content">
          <div className="image">
             <img src={loginImg} />
          </div>
          <div className="form">
             <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="username"
                    placeholder="username"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setUsernameReg(e.target.value);
                    }}
                    value={usernameReg} //Don't forget about use value attribute from state
                />
             </div>
             <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" />
             </div>
             <div className="form-group">
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="password"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setPasswordReg(e.target.value);
                    }}
                    value={passwordReg} //Don't forget about use value attribute from state
                />
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="footer">
          <button type="button" onClick={register} className="btn">
          Register
          </button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```